# does router have a public IP address?

Tags: networking, router, ip

I am trying to find my router public IP address, does router have a public IP address?if so then How to find router public IP address on windows?

Comment: Go to Google. Type "What's my IP address"

Comment: What is your router hooked up to (the WAN port). It may or may not have a public IP address. In addition to the other suggestion, open up the main web GUI page of the router and see what address the WAN port has.

Answer (score 2):

A Public IP Address is often referred to as the IP Address that is assigned to a customer by their ISP. It is the address that connects a pc to the outside world.

All routers have a WAN Ip Address, but it does not have to be the public ip address.

For example, the modem could also be a router and a second router is behind it, then the 2nd router's WAN IP Address is not the same as the public IP Address. Instead, the router's WAN IP Address is assigned an internal IP address from the modem.

```
For example, you have public IP: 123.45.67.89.
Modem's WAN 1 ip: 123.45.67.89.
Modem's LAN ip: 10.10.1.1
Modem's LAN range: 10.10.1.10 - 10.10.1.100
Modem has 1 client, the router, DHCP assigns it 10.10.1.11

Router's WAN 1 ip: 10.10.1.11
Router's LAN 1 ip: 192.168.1.1
Router's LAN range: 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.100
Your pc: DHCP assigned 192.168.1.15
```

The public ip is: 123.45.67.89, the router's WAN ip is 10.10.1.11

To find a router's WAN IP Address, login to the router's admin center, and locate the status page, often the first thing you see after logging in. It contains the WAN IP Address.

To find the public IP address that connects you to the internet, go to a page such as [www.whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/). It is also possible to login to the admin center of the modem and find it on its status page, but the internet site is easier and quicker.

Comment: I'm not sure why everybody recommends whatsmyip.com - you can just type into the search bar in any browser & your search engine will tell you. They'll do the same for simple calculations "1+2*3", unit conversions "3.47m in inches" etc

Comment: @Tetsujin for a few reasons. 1 This is a clickable link, 2. it is easy to remember, 3. it will work regardless of what search engine you have, 4. it generally does not cause any confusion.